# Rails Active Model Serializer - Custom Serializer on AMS 0.10 - group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have updated `active_model_serializer` from `0.9.3` to `0.10.0` as I want to use the json_api adapter. Once updated, I no longer can use both my model serializer along with my custom serializer. Here's my backtrace:

```sh
[active_model_serializers] Rendered GroupedProjectsSerializer with 
ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi (6.03ms)

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for 
#<Hash:0x007f90cbed0ba8>):...
```

I have also tried including `ActiveModel::Serialization` in the custom serializer which then I get another error as below:

```sh
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<GroupedItemSerializer:0x007fa47012ad38>):...
```

adding `attributes :id` doesn't resolve the issue though.

Here's my setup:

**Initializer:**

```rb
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

**Model Serializer:**

```rb
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :code, :name, :item_type, ....
end
```

**Custom Serializer:**

```rb
class GroupedItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   def serializable_object(options = {})
      @object.map do |group_key, items|
         [group_key, serialized_items(items)]
      end.to_h
   end

   private

   def serialized_items(items)
      items.map do |item|
         ItemSerializer.new(item, root: false)
      end
   end
end
```

**Controller:**

```rb
@items = Item.all.group_by(&:item_type)

# using each_serializer also doesn't help as it only uses the 
# GroupedItemserializer and not applying the ItemSerializer!
render json: @items, serializer: GroupedItemSerializer
```

Not sure if I'm missing something in the documentation, but I've tried all the possible ways to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `render json: @items, serializer: GroupedItemSerializer` to `render json: @items, each_serializer: GroupedItemSerializer`

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention, I have tried that too, but then my default serializer isn't applied!

Comment: did you try ```class GroupedItemSerializer < ItemSerializer```

Comment: I finally decided to use 0.9.3 and change my data structure anyway so not to need the custom serializers as much as possible.